# Generate array of floats within possible MAX and MIN

Tags: python, numpy, random, floating-point

I'm trying to generate floats however not within [0-1) but `sys.float_info.max` and `sys.float_info.min`. Unfortunately Python's random and Numpy random work as this way

```
a + (b-a) * random()
```

But random() does not generate small enough numbers to compete with exponent of MAX float.

```
print min([random.uniform(0, sys.float_info.max) for i in range(10000)])
>>2.0237842876e+304
```

How to generate floats from 0 - MAX(float) or MIN(float) to MAX(float)?

Comment: What are the requirements for the distribution?

Comment: Uniform distribution, as in the code.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the uniform distribution. Recall that there are ~20,000 more numbers between 1E+304 and `sys.float_info.max` (2E+308) than between 0 and 1E+304. i.e. because you are selecting 10k numbers between 0 and 2E+308, the lowest value is likely to be around 2E+304.

Comment: There are tricks that could be used if uniform were not actually required. As @farenorth notes, sampling a uniform distribution over the full range will rarely produce a moderate value.

Comment: Also note that `sys.float_info.min` is 2.22E-308 (i.e. it is very close to 0), and is NOT `- sys.float_info.max`. In other words, `random.uniform(sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.max)` and `random.uniform(0, sys.float_info.max)` should give nearly identical results.

Comment: I know it's not 0, and when I try with `sys.float_info.min` then I have `inf` because of the formulation I posted. You are right there are more numbers in that region but after several tests I should see below that threshold as well, since it's uniform distribution. Problem, as I see it, `random.random()` itself because it produces minimum of `e-6`. When multiplied with the difference `(a + (b-a))` it can't go below `e-300`

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan what would you suggest if the distribution is relaxed?

Comment: `np.random.rand` does not have a lower limit of `1e-6`. For example, try `np.random.rand(1e8).min()`. You simply have to sample MANY values to ever get one in that range. This is the nature of the uniform distribution. To get a value `<1e-300` you would have to sample `1e300` random values, which will generate a memory error. The limitation is processing power, not a built-in error or limitation of the algorithm.

Comment: @HalilKaskavalci Suppose, for example, you could make it uniform over the set of representable, positive, finite, normal numbers. That means you would generate with equal probability, each of the bit patterns with sign bit 0, exponent in the range 0x001 through 0x7fe, significand any 52 bit number. You could either build it up from random integers, or take a random long and throw away the ones that don't fit.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't seem to be expecting behavior you should expect from a uniform distribution - see @farenorth's comments. How do you intend to use these numbers? What are you modelling?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just simply generate both parts of your random numbers by joining integer part and float.

```
random.uniform(sys.float_info.min, sys.float_info.max) + random.random()
```

Comment: That's a clever trick but random.random() does not give small enough numbers (i.e `e-300`). Then I'll have numbers within the range with only 6-7 fraction.

Comment: I think you can generate big enough number and then divide it by degree of 10 for your needs, but probably I really don't know your problems field. Just an idea `random.randint(0, 10e300)/float(10e300)` but not sure if float have so much digits after period, but if you just need to generate number and use it outside of the code after you can just use `random.randint(0, 10e300)` part

Answer (score 0):

Best way that I found to generate any random float within possible range is generating a random byte sequence and parse it as float.

```
import os, struct, math
#float32
rand_num = struct.unpack('f', os.urandom(4))[0]
if not math.isnan(rand_num):
  print rand_num

#float64 aka double
rand_num = struct.unpack('d', os.urandom(8))[0]
if not math.isnan(rand_num):
  print rand_num
```

Answer (score 0):

We can *view* the floats `sys.float_info.min` and `sys.float_info.max` as `int64`s:

```
imin = np.float64(sys.float_info.min).view('int64')
imax = np.float64(sys.float_info.max).view('int64')

In [298]: imin, imax
Out[298]: (4503599627370496, 9218868437227405311)
```

We can then generate random integers between `imin` and `imax` and view them as `float64`s:

```
In [299]: np.random.random_integers(imin, imax, size=10).view('float64')
Out[299]: 
array([  2.88648634e+084,   3.52929128e+117,   4.92852196e-157,
         1.19367593e+214,   3.72292917e-171,   7.00063144e+121,
         9.06356989e+141,   9.13489394e-054,   1.29622916e-304,
         2.04781344e+064])
```

As the integers increase from `imin` to `imax`, so do the corresponding floats
increase from `sys.float_info.min` to `sys.float_info.max`.

The integer(s) corresponding to `float('inf')` and `float('nan')` lie outside the interval `[imin, imax]`, so you don't have to worry about generating `inf`s or `nan`s.

```
In [323]: np.arange(imax, imax+5).view('float64')
Out[323]: 
array([  1.79769313e+308,               inf,               nan,
                     nan,               nan])
```

---

Warning: As `farenorth` points out, the numbers representable as floats are not
evenly distributed. There are many more floats between 0 and 1 than there are between 1 and 2, and far more again than there are 
between large floats. Thus, the method below does not generate
a random sample from a *uniform* distribution.